# Gradle build ran through TFS fails because of Android licenses not being agreed upon

Tags: android, gradle, tfs

I'm trying to set up an automated build for an Android app from Team Foundation Services, using Gradle. Almost everything is correctly set up, but the build fails each time because two modules that the app is dependent upon do not have their licenses agreed upon. This is what I'm getting as an error output:

```
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 in 
C:\Tools\AndroidSdk\licenses
License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 (revision: 28.0.3)".
Warning: Failed to read or create install properties file.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 28 in 
C:\Tools\AndroidSdk\licenses
License for package Android SDK Platform 28 accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 28 (revision: 6)".
Warning: Failed to read or create install properties file.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to install the following SDK components:
      build-tools;28.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3
      platforms;android-28 Android SDK Platform 28
Install the missing components using the SDK manager in Android Studio.
```

I've already tried pretty much everything I found on StackOverflow or other places. I deleted all licenses from %ANDROID_HOME%/Licenses folder, installed them again and agreed the terms (with sdkmanager.bat --licenses command); I added a PowerShell script that copies each license file for each module from %ANDROID_HOME%/Licenses folder to the output folder; I reinstalled the whole SDK; I've made sure that the agent has permissions to edit and delete files in the working folders. I've also tried running the build directly from the build server (without a TFS agent) and it successfully built, which is also strange.

Am I missing another thing I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We fixed the issue by running an "--update" command on the sdkmanager.bat file in the folder where we have the SDK installed. A few modules from the SDK got updated and the error went away.

It is possible to have the "--update" command as a script step in the build definition on TFS, so the error does not come back eventually when one of the modules will be updated.